# What does the phrase ''many among the listeners'' mean?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

In the following context, Should I take the bold sentence as "There are many (listeners) who are not Buddhists among the listeners"?
I think the relative pronoun "who" modifies the word "many".
How should I do that?

the context:

> **There are many among the listeners who are not Buddhists**, and to whom therefore, in many cases, the original teaching of the Buddha is a thing almost unknown.

source:

page: 1
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka mahâthera

Comment: That's right. Similarly, "There are some among us who..." = "Some of us..."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is correct. "Many" is a pronoun, heading the phrase "many among the listeners", and it is modifed by the relative clause "who are not Buddhists". (Some might consider "many" an adjective, but the analysis would be similar.)

Comment: yes, I did correctly as it is.

Comment: Not textthing'' , surely it is  ''thing''.

Comment: @SakyaKim I think James K fixed it. I've therefore deleted the second paragraph of my answer.